# why it is called context switch? why not Process Swap or Swapping,cause resources are same

Tags: operating-system, context-switch

> The process of a Context Switch. In computing, a context switch is the
>   process of storing and restoring the state (more specifically, the
>   execution context) of a process or thread so that execution can be
>   resumed from the same point at a later time.

but if it is the process or thread 
and resource is not shared then **it must be called as Process Swap or Thread Swap**

Answer (score 2):

It is not swapping threads themselves or process themselves. It is swapping execution context information stored within the CPU - various CPU registers, flag bits, etc. A process contains 1+ threads, and each thread manipulates CPU state.  A context switch captures the CPU state (the context) of the current running thread and pauses it, then swaps in the state of another thread so it can then resume running where it previously left off.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in minds that it was called a change in process context long before there were threads. Since we are talking history, I ignore threads.

Making a process executable requires loading registers. The set of registers varies among systems but it typically includes:

- General Registers
- Processor Status
- Use Page Table Registers

When a process ceases to be current, its register values need to be saved. When the process becomes current, its register values need to be restored.

Nearly every processor has an instruction that performs each of these tasks to allow the switch to be performed atomically.

The processor then needs to define a data structure for holding the register values. For whatever reason, this data structure was called a "Process Context Block"  or PCB (some idiotic textbooks use PCB to describe something else that does not really exist).

Someone probably thought calling it a Process "Context" was a cute name. It really does not make sense in English but that is what happened.

The instructions for loading and saving then became variants of Load Process Context and Save Process Context.

> but if it is the process or thread and resource is not shared then it must be called as Process Swap or Thread Swap

Swapping is an entirely different concept. So the terms "swap" and "swapping" were already taken. In the days before paging, entire processes were moved (swapped) to disk. That is why eunuchs has a "swap" partition—the name never got updated to "page partition."